# How does many-worlds interpretation explain Interference of the wave function and interaction free measurement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

According to the many-worlds interpretation there inst any superposition. But for example  in the Elitzur–Vaidman bomb  experience the photon is Interfering with itself.
If the universes have no effect on each other how can the photon Interference with itself. And how can the fact that the bomb was real or not effect the universe  where the photon didn't took the path of the bomb.
I was using these two sources

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitzur%E2%80%93Vaidman_bomb_tester

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation

Comment: I cannot make a formal answer, but when I discovered that the many worlds interpretation  is taking literally the path integral formulation of quantum mechanics, I stopped worrying about such questions as you state.  "interpretation" means that the same physical numbers to be checked,come out by the calculations.  see this https://thereader.mitpress.mit.edu/the-many-worlds-theory/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My humble thoughts:

According to MWI (Many-Worlds Interpretation), when the photon passes the first glass, the universe splits into 2. In one the photon goes up, and in the other down.

If there's no bomb in the bottom path, in both universes the photon reaches the second glass.

**Now, MWI clarifies that the universes are never 100% split, in rare circumstances (like here) they can interact again.**

The photons in each universe interact with each other (they are at the same place at the same time, and they are from 'compatible universes', whatever that means), causing both of them to go always to the same detector, C.

Now both universes are identical again. Are they recombined into a single universe? I don't know.

Note that only universes that have **a lot** in common, like those 2, can interact like that. Which is why we only see it in very specific quantum experiments.

If your experiment is open to external disturbances, they can make each universe 'less compatible', in which case the 'inter-universe interaction' will be diminished: the 'weird quantum effects' will be less visible.

If there's a bomb in the bottom path, the photon in the second universe never reaches the last glass. So the photon in the first universe feels no foreign interaction and, again, splits the first universe into 2: in one the photon goes to detector C, and in the other, D. Here you have 3 universes.

Comment: so basically the answer is that only very similar  universe can interact so when one of the photons interact with the boom they don't similar enough  so the photon wont interfere

Comment: Be careful about the basis problem. The term "superposition" depends on what basis you pick. For example, there exists a perfectly well-defined basis such that after the beam splitter the photon state here is in just one of the states of that basis (not a superposition of two). So the "split" mentioned in MWI is not here. It has to be something to do with irreversible measurement-like interactions (something not very well specified in most attempts to present the MWI).

Comment: @AndrewSteane "irreversible measurement-like interactions" is an ill defined concept. There is nothing fundamentaly different between a photon hitting a splitter glass and a phton hitting a detector screen, both are made of atoms that obey QM. Either all interactions cause an MWI split, or none do.

Comment: @JuanPerez (1) No, the measurement-like interactions have a preferred basis. It is the one in which off-diagonal density matrix elements either evolve very quickly, or decay, or go to zero after tracing over some third-party system. (2) A detector involves of order Avogadro's number of atoms (or similar) having state changes of a complicated avalanche-like character which will never be undone in the future evolution of the universe. A beam splitter is not like this. (3) The evolution $u \rightarrow v + w$ can equally well be written $u_+ + u_- \rightarrow x$ where $x = v + w$.

Comment: @AndrewSteane Like I said before, (1) & (2) are arbitrary. It's a continuum, you don't have a clear cut way to separate interactions into either type. You can't say that a detector with 9999..9998 atoms doesn't do measurements, but one with 9999...9999 does. You can only say that, the bigger it is, the more measurement-like it is. The closer to zero the off diagonals become, the more measurement-like it is. But again, smallness is a continuum, there's no precise threshold that you cross and say, "this is now a measurement". That's the whole Measurement Problem

Answer (score 4):

In the original [Everett Interpretation](https://cqi.inf.usi.ch/qic/everett_phd.pdf), there are no parallel universes, only pure superposition. When Bryce DeWitt - an early populariser of the theory - was trying to explain to a lay audience back in the 1970s how it worked, he described the superpositions as being *as if* each possibility existed in a separate world, and the description stuck - hence the alternative name of 'Many Worlds Interpretation'. While the image has successfully propelled the idea into the public consciousness, it has posed endless problems for its acceptance among physicists. All the questions previously raised about wavefunction collapse, which the Everett Interpretation had answered, simply got raised again with regard to the creation or splitting or interaction of new universes.

The Everett Interpretation does not need to invent any new metaphysical machinery like extra universes to work. It just takes the unitary evolution of quantum mechanics *that physicists following Bohr's Copenhagen Interpretation already agreed happened* on the microscopic level and pointed out that if you took it seriously and extended it to the macroscopic level, it already predicted that *quantum observers would experience classical, one-possibility-at-a-time observations*. When a quantum observer interacted with a quantum system, the observer would evolve into a superposition of orthogonal states, in each of which the observer saw a different outcome, and which (being orthogonal) *didn't interact*. They only affect each other by interference, the only observable consequence of which is to change various probabilities.

This is no different to the way an electron passing through one slit does not see itself simultaneously passing through the other slit (for example, they do not repel one another electrostatically). An electron cloud surrounding an atom does not see the rest of the cloud: it does not have any contribution to energy from self-repulsion, as a classical cloud of negative electrical charge in such a confined space would. Quantum mechanics is linear. If two solutions are added, the sum is also a solution. It means there can be no interaction terms between the superposed components.

In short, *there is* no measurement problem. Unitary quantum mechanics *already* provides an explanation for why we see what we do. It was only sloppy thinking that led us to believe that in a macroscopic quantum universe we would see fuzzy clouds of possibilities overlapping; ghostly cats leaping out of boxes containing their own semi-transparent corpses, and so on. The Everett Interpretation requires no additional physics, no new assumptions - it is a *subset* of the Copenhagen Interpretation.

So as far as the unitary evolution of interfering waves goes (Elitzur-Vaidman bomb tests, EPR experiments, double slit, etc.), MWI is *identical* to the Copenhagen Interpretation. It simply re-iterates it. They only differ in what they say about the *observation* process. In MWI, unitary evolution leads to a superposition of mutually-invisible observers, each seeing exactly one outcome. In the Copenhagen Interpretation, all but one of these alternatives simply *vanishes*. The surviving alternative is selected completely at random, with a probability distribution given by a rule that has to be simply asserted as an axiom. The mechanism by which this happens is unexplained - proposals range from the unknown physics of quantum gravity, the possibility of as-yet undetected higher order non-linearities, to more mystical explanations involving the role of consciousness, intelligence, and vitalism. Their vanishing also has awkward metaphysical implications for faster-than-light, backwards-in-time (e.g. the quantum eraser experiment) effects.

Since the interpretations only differ in their claims about things that can never be observed, even in principle, there is no way to distinguish them experimentally. (At least, if quantum mechanics is correct. If it's not, the new observations might be more compatible with modifications to one alternative than another.) The only grounds on which to select between them are aesthetic - which of them is more mathematically elegant, simple, parsimonious, easy to calculate with, etc.

Comment: "Their vanishing also has awkward metaphysical implications for faster-than-light, backwards-in-time (e.g. the quantum eraser experiment) effects." - true enough about FTL, but I don't see what you mean about backward in time. There is no problem with modeling any quantum-eraser setup in an objective-collapse picture. Talking heads on YouTube say silly things about quantum-eraser experiments proving back-in-time causation, but that isn't the "fault" of objective-collapse QM.

Comment: Incidentally, I keep seeing answers by Nullius in Verba, but it's always a new unregistered user. I wish you'd create an account so it's possible to reach you; I don't know if you'll even see these comments. You can still be "nobody" with a pseudonymous account.

Comment: FTL always implies backwards-in-time. The delayed-choice quantum eraser is just an especially weird example as it allows you to decide whether it's a wave or particle after the measurement has been made. Of course there is no problem modelling *any* quantum experiment with a collapse interpretation - like I said, they're experimentally indistinguishable. [Regarding registering, my objection is primarily philosophical - I don't like the idea of relying on 'reputation' in matters of science. But I also don't want to be reached. I learn a lot from SE; I enjoy giving back a bit, that's all.]

Comment: But a system that is in a superposition in some basis, can be in an eigenstate in another basis, or in a different superposition in a different basis. An observer that exists when describing the system in some basis doesn't exist when describing it in another one...

Answer (score 1):

According to the many worlds interpretation (MWI) each system exists in multiple versions. Those versions can interfere with one another under some circumstances. But if information is copied out of the system while it is undergoing interference this may prevent interference by a process called decoherence. When a system decoheres its different versions won't interfere with one another and can be regarded as being in different universes because they don't affect one another. Universes are an approximate, emergent consequence of quantum mechanics and the parallel universe approximation isn't always correct. In this case, it's wrong during the Elitzur-Vaidman bomb experiment.

"The Fabric of Reality" and "The Beginning of Infinity" by David Deutsch have some pop science explanations of the MWI.

The following papers explain aspects of the MWI:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0103092

https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2832

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033